# Does opening a new terminal tab use equivalent system resources to opening a new window when running scripts in parallel?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, performance, cpu, process

Is opening a new tab in the terminal window equivalent to opening a new tab in terms of resources?

I need to run 16 scripts in parallel. I do not know whether opening tabs or new terminals is the best practice. I want to get the maximum performance but without exhausting the resources to an extent that degrades the performance.

Comment: Close voters: Answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is never fully equivalent in terms of resources (I assume system resources), because a window is different than a tab. Whether, for 16 windows or tabs, it will make any practical/relevant difference is another matter. You of course can test.

There are other ways to save resources. You can also run a single terminal, and run the 16 processes in the background. Yet (much) better in terms of saving resources is to avoid running a graphical server all together. Have the system boot to a terminal and run the processes there. This will save you several hundreds of megabytes of RAM to start with.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is extremely minimal and unlikely to make a difference in your use case (assuming relatively current hardware) although it does appear that gnome terminal server uses slightly less memory for tabs than for windows. This is easy to see in System Monitor.

Four Windows shows memory utilization similar to this:

[image: 4windows]

Four Tabs shows memory utilization similar to this:

[image: 4tabs]

Answer (score 0):

**About the resources used by the windows/tabs**

Intuitively and like Elder Geek measured in his [response](https://askubuntu.com/a/1082940/454520), tabs should use less memory.

The difference not really significant, even the absolute value is not significant in today's computers. The thing you should care about is the **time to print text in the terminal**.

**Example with numbers**

Let's take a simple command : `find test`. It will print the name of all files in a the `test` directory. This directory contains 55483 files, for a total of 4935616 characters to be written in the terminal.

Here is how I measure the time elapsed, using the `time` command:

```
time find test
...
**** lot of printed chars
...
real    0m5.017s
user    0m0.175s
sys     0m0.221s
```

This test took 5.0 seconds, now here are some test results:

```
+---------------------------+-------------------------------------------+--------------+
|          Command          |                 remarks                   |   duration   |
+---------------------------+-------------------------------------------+--------------+
| find test                 | terminal                                  | 5.1 seconds  |
| find test                 | terminal (hidden behind another window)   | 5.5 seconds  |
| find test                 | terminal (minimized)                      | 5.5 seconds  |
| find test > /tmp/test.txt | output redirected to a file               | 0.1 seconds  |
| find test                 | text console                              | > 10 seconds |
| find test                 | text console, switched to another console | 0.3 seconds  |
+---------------------------+-------------------------------------------+--------------+
```

I won't do any more test, I think you've got the point.

**Conclusion**

The performance of your scripts will also depend of how much they write to the terminal.